# Mongoengine Connection Failure: You have not defined a default connection

Tags: python, fastapi, mongoengine

Start a python project, using fastapi with mongoengine. Yesterday it was working normally, but today when running any method that has the connection to the database, the connection failure error occurs (mongoengine.connection.ConnectionFailure: You have not defined a default connection ).

My connection:

```
from mongoengine import connect

connect(db="mydb", host='localhost', port=27017, alias='default')
```

My models:

```
from mongoengine.document import Document
from mongoengine.fields import StringField, BooleanField, ListField, ReferenceField
from mongoengine import PULL


class Permissao(Document):
    permissao = StringField()


class Grupo(Document):
    grupo = StringField()
    
    permissoes = ListField(ReferenceField('Permissao', reverse_delete_rule=PULL))


class Usuario(Document):
    nome_usuario = StringField()
    ativo = BooleanField()
    senha = StringField()
    
    grupos = ListField(ReferenceField('Grupo', reverse_delete_rule=PULL))
    permissoes = ListField(ReferenceField('Permissao', reverse_delete_rule=PULL))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked, I switched the connection to the models and put a meta field, check it below:

```
from mongoengine.document import Document
from mongoengine.fields import StringField, BooleanField, ListField, ReferenceField
from mongoengine import PULL
from mongoengine import connect

connect(db="mydb", host="localhost", port=27017, alias="mydb-alias")

class Permissao(Document):
    permissao = StringField()

    meta = {"db_alias" : "mydb-alias" , "collection" : "permissao"}


class Grupo(Document):
    grupo = StringField()
    
    permissoes = ListField(ReferenceField('Permissao', reverse_delete_rule=PULL))
    
    meta = {"db_alias" : "mydb-alias" , "collection" : "grupo"}


class Usuario(Document):
    nome_usuario = StringField()
    ativo = BooleanField()
    senha = StringField()
    
    grupos = ListField(ReferenceField('Grupo', reverse_delete_rule=PULL))
    permissoes = ListField(ReferenceField('Permissao', reverse_delete_rule=PULL))

    meta = {"db_alias" : "mydb-alias" , "collection" : "usuario"}
```